# R - data frame switch rows and columns

Tags: r, dataframe, transformation

I have data frame looking like this:

```
category fan_id likes
A     10702397  1
B     10702397  4
A     35003154  1
B     35003154  1
C     35003154  2
```

I'd like to convert it into a following data frame

```
fan_id   A B C
10702397 1 4 0
35003154 1 1 2
```

The only way that I can think of is looping over the data frame and constructing another manually but it seems like there has to be a better way.

It seems like I want to the opposite of what was asked here [Switch column to row in a data.frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16232192/switch-column-to-row-in-a-data-frame)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
> library(reshape2)
> dat <- data.frame(category=c("A","B","A","B","C"),fan_id=c(10702397,10702397,35003154,35003154,35003154),likes=c(1,4,1,1,2))
> dcast(dat,fan_id~category,fill=0)
Using likes as value column: use value.var to override.
    fan_id A B C
1 10702397 1 4 0
2 35003154 1 1 2
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, sometimes the accept time limit is to restrictive :)

Comment: I assumed that you were looking for a data frame object returned, dcast is for data frames whereas acast would return a matrix.

Comment: Even still it isn't a bad question, understanding Hadley's naming conventions can really cut down on the amount of documentation reading you have to do :)

Answer (score 4):

Base `reshape` function method:

```
dat <- data.frame(
       category=c("A","B","A","B","C"),
       fan_id=c(10702397,10702397,35003154,35003154,35003154),
       likes=c(1,4,1,1,2)
                 )
result <- reshape(dat,idvar="fan_id",timevar="category",direction="wide")
names(result)[2:4] <- gsub("^.*\\.","",names(result)[2:4])
result

    fan_id A B  C
1 10702397 1 4 NA
3 35003154 1 1  2
```

Bonus `xtabs` method:

```
result2 <- as.data.frame.matrix(xtabs(likes ~ fan_id + category, data=dat))

         A B C
10702397 1 4 0
35003154 1 1 2
```

Exact format with a fix:

```
data.frame(fan_id=rownames(result2),result2,row.names=NULL)

    fan_id A B C
1 10702397 1 4 0
2 35003154 1 1 2
```

Comment: +1 faster than me ! Might I suggest that you add `result[is.na(result)] <- 0` since OP wants 0 and not NA.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, dcast seems much more concise so I'm going with that one

Answer (score 3):

Here's a `data.table` alternative:

```
require(data.table)
dt <- as.data.table(df) # where df is your original data.frame
out <- dt[CJ(unique(fan_id), unique(category))][, 
       setattr(as.list(likes), 'names', as.character(category)), 
       by = fan_id][is.na(C), C := 0L]

#      fan_id A B C
# 1: 10702397 1 4 0
# 2: 35003154 1 1 2
```

Answer (score 3):

The shortest solution I could think of only consists of typing a one-letter method.

The transpose function `t` also works on dataframes, not just on matrices.

#### Example

```
> data = data.frame(a = c(1,2,3), b = c(4,5,6))
> data 
  a b
1 1 4
2 2 5
3 3 6
> t(data)
  [,1] [,2] [,3]
a    1    2    3
b    4    5    6
```

Documentation can be found [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/t.html).

Comment: This was what I was looking for. Found so many solutions for more complicated problems, but I just wanted to transpose my data.  Thanks!